# Flex Mobile Event Listener not firing

Tags: mobile, flex4, event-handling, flash-builder4.5

I'm having trouble getting an event listener to work in a mobile app (Built in Flash Builder 4.5, Flex SDK 4.5.1)

I have an event class called BMS_Event.as which looks like this:

```
package model
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class BMS_Event extends Event
{

    public static var COMPLETE_EVENT:String = "BMSData_Complete";

    public static var FAULT:String = "BMSDatafault";

    public var data:*;

    public function BMS_Event(type:String, data:*=null, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        this.data = data;
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

}

A class to dispatch the event:

```
package model
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

import model.BMS_Event;

public class BMSDataParser extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function BMSDataParser()
    {
        trace("BMSDataParser function");
        var BMSDataCompleteEvent:BMS_Event = new BMS_Event(BMS_Event.COMPLETE_EVENT);
        dispatchEvent(BMSDataCompleteEvent);
    }
}
```

}

And in my Mobile App view, two functions to call the eventparser, and then an eventlistener which listens for the complete event:

```
    import model.BMSDataParser;
import model.BMS_Event;

protected function getData():void
{
    var parser:BMSDataParser = new BMSDataParser();
    parser.addEventListener(BMS_Event.COMPLETE_EVENT, bmstest);
}

private function bmstest(e:BMS_Event):void
{
    trace("bmstest function");
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the event listener isn't firing, everything works fine up until that point.  It does work in a web application, but for whatever reason not a mobile app.
I'm new to mobile app development - is this a limitation of AIR mobile Apps?

Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately it didn't change anything.  After a bit more debugging, it looks like the problem is the event is being dispatched before the eventlistener is added.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make `var parser:BMSDataParser` a private class variable, and in the `creationComplete` or `initialized` events of the class add `parser.addEventListener(BMS_Event.COMPLETE_EVENT, bmstest);`

One more thing: if your using ViewNavigatorApplication with Views, the views are not created until they are pushed onto the view stack e.g. `navigator.pushView(PayNowView);`, so any listeners will not be activated unless they are displayed first